# Flash Builder Rss feed works, but have to link each article to it's original webpage. How?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, rss, flash-builder, flex4.5

Below is the code from my Flash Builder 4.5 project that gives an RSS-feed. The feed is showing correctly, but I'm having some problems with linking each news-article. So when you click in a article title, it should link to the according webpage. I have been able to extract the url for each article (3th column in the datagrid) and i also created a basic function that links to google when you click on the datagrid. What I need is that when you click on a row, you go to the according webpage. ANy help is welcome!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                creationComplete="runningrssfeedstart(event)">
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="runningrssfeed"
                   url="{rss_request}"
                   result="runningrssfeed_resultHandler(event)"
                   fault="runningrssfeed_faultHandler(event)"/>

    <s:ArrayCollection id="myAc"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        //imported classes
        import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.mx_internal;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.formatters.DateBase;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.object_proxy;

        [Bindable]
        public var rss_request:String;


        //parameters voor rss-feed + opdracht de httpservice te starten
        public function runningrssfeedstart(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            rss_request = 'http://www.coolrunning.com/engine/affiliate/rssLatest.rss';
            runningrssfeed.send();
        }

        //Als rss werkt, neem dan info van volgende pad
        protected function runningrssfeed_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            myAc = event.result.rss.channel.item;
        }

        //Als rss functie mislukt, toon dan alert mat fault string
        protected function runningrssfeed_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(event.fault.faultString);
        }

        //opent site van nieuwsbericht hoe google veranderen in juiste url?
        public function openRss(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:DataGrid click="openRss(event)" left="105" top="45" width="450" height="380" dataProvider="{myAc}" headerStyleName="headerBold">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn id="rssTitel" width="320" headerText="Artikel" dataField="title"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Datum" dataField="pubDate"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="url" dataField="link"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Use `itemClick` i.s.o `click` which is the general event handler for any click on the datagrid. For more information checkout http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_7.html

Comment: Thanks. But how exactly can i link to the according news article? I'm trying some new things, if i find a solution i'll comment again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Spark [DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html) instead of the mx DataGrid (and I can think of no reason why you shouldn't) you can simply use its '[gridClick](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event%3agridClick)' event handler like this:

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}" gridClick="openRssAt(event.rowIndex)">      
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="title" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="pubDate" />
            <s:GridColumn dataField="link" />
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>

public function openRssAt(index:int):void {
    var url:String = dp.getItemAt(index).link;
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url), "_blank");
}
```

However, if you wish to stick with mx DataGrid, you can use the `itemClick` event handler in exactly the same way:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{dp}" itemClick="openRssAt(event.rowIndex)">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="title"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="pubDate"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="link"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```